# Negate exit code without using shell features

Tags: exit

Is there any standard command that will negate the the exit code of another command provided as an argument without using shell features, or starting a shell?

I have a program that does something based on exit code of an `system()` call.  I have another program that returns its status via the exit code.  But the program I am calling returns the results opposite from what I want.  I can simply specify something like `bash -c '....'`, but is there an easier way?

P.S.  Yes, I know I am probably trying to optimize something that probably doesn't really matter all that much.  But mostly I am curious, since unix seems to have a command for almost everything, why I can't find a simple negate-the-exit-code command.

Comment: Like sch, I don't think there is an easier way. But use `sh -c ...` not `bash -c ...`; it may be much faster for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "negate"? Exit codes aren't boolean.

Comment: On these particular systems /bin/sh is just a symlink to bash.  I could install a lightweight shell.  The performance isn't that big of a deal really.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe, lets assume that 0=true (like /bin/true), and anything else is false.  So if the exit is not 0 then return 0, and if it is zero, then return something not zero.

Comment: Are you talking about `C`?  The `exec` family of functions don't actually return.  Are you talking about `system()` instead?

Comment: @jw013, not really certain about the calling program.  I don't have the source to it.  You are right, it probably is `system()` or something similar.  I suppose I could use `strace()` and figure out, but what is doing the calling is really not the main point of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Not in the standard tool set AFAIK. `sh` (and its `!`) in the standard tool set would be the closest to what you want.

```
system("sh", "-c",  "! \"$0\" \"$@\"", "cmd", "arg1", "arg2"...)
```

Other tools that can execute commands either don't have that feature (find, env, xargs...) or call a shell themselves (ed, awk...) to execute a command.

Early unices had an "if" command, but it disappeared with the Bourne shell that brought extended control statements.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
[ ! `<yourFirtsCommand>` ]
```

Replace `<yourFirtsCommand>` with your command. 
I recommend you use the right kind of quotes!

to avoid problems with [ ] you can use:

```
test ! `<yourFirtsCommand>`
```

Comment: This is probably not what you want. What this will do is collect the string output of `yourFirtsCommand`, and negate it. Negating a empty string returns 0 (shell-speak for true), and negating a non-empty string returns 1. This will give you trouble if the output has spaces in it (in that case you need an extra layer of `"..."` quotes), and it will ignore the exit code of `yourFirtsCommand`. Plus a shell is needed to handle the angle quotes; I don't think you could just directly exec `/bin\[` to get this result. The best solution will just use a shell and `!` without `[...]`.

Comment: You're right, the command in principle is wrong, but it may work in its specific case!

Comment: i would also argue that `<yourFirtsCommand>` its a shell feature